# Kotlin typealias of generic supertype with bound type parameter not working for inheritance

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, mvp, type-alias

TL;DR why does this work:

```
interface SomeInterface
interface Generic <T : SomeInterface> {}
class Self : Generic<Self>, SomeInterface
```

And this doesn't:

```
interface SomeInterface
interface Generic <T : SomeInterface> {}
typealias Specified = Generic<Self>
class Self : Specified, SomeInterface
```

> Error: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of
>   'SomeInterface'

Error says it isn't right subtype, but it is!

The use case of such typealias comes from real-life code, where a superclass has 5 type parameters, each with rather long name, and I don't want to pollute class header with unnecessary spam. Any ideas? I'm using kotlin 1.2.51.

**--- Original problem ---**

MVP interfaces:

```
interface MVPComponent // dagger component 
interface MVPComponentHolder<C : MVPComponent> // implementing class must provide component
interface MVPArgs // args passed from view to presenter on attach
interface MVPView<A : MVPArgs> // MVP View, must provide Args for presenter
interface MVPPresenter<T : MVPView<A>, A : MVPArgs, U : MVPUseCase>
interface MVPUseCase // selected API methods to use in presenter
```

Base Fragment for MVP:

```
abstract class MVPFragment<F, V, P, A, C>
    : Fragment(), MVPComponentHolder<C>
    where F : V,
          V : MVPView<A>,
          P : MVPPresenter<V, A, *>,
          C : MVPComponent<V>,
          A : MVPArgs {
    // lots of MVP logic
}
```

MVP contract:

```
interface ExampleMVP {
    data class Args(/* ... */) : MVPArgs

    interface View : MVPView<Args> {
        //...
    }
    interface Presenter : MVPPresenter<View, Args, UseCase> {
        //...
    }
    interface UseCase : MVPUseCase<View> {
        //...
    }
}
```

Final fragment:

```
class ExampleFragment : MVPFragment<
    ExampleFragment,
    ExampleMVP.View,
    ExampleMVP.Presenter,
    ExampleMVP.Args,
    ExampleMVP>(), ExampleMVP.View {
    // final fragment logic
}
```

But I would like to use following syntax:

```
private typealias SuperFragment = MVPFragment<
        ExampleFragment,
        ExampleMVP.View,
        ExampleMVP.Presenter,
        ExampleMVP.Args,
        ExampleMVP>

class ExampleFragment : SuperFragment(), ExampleMVP.View {
    // final fragment logic
}
```

The reason I pass `ExampleFragment` as type argument of `MVPFragment` is because Dagger 2 must inject directly into target class (in this case not just `Fragment` or `MVPFragment`, but `ExampleFragment`), or injection code will not be generated.

The injection in `MVPFragment` looks the following way:

```
@CallSuper
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    component.injectIntoView(this as F) // must be target fragment type (here F)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the circular dependency introduced by:

```
class Self : Specified, SomeInterface
```

If `Self` does not inherit from `Specified` it works.

The changed example looks like this.

```
interface SomeInterface
interface Generic <T : SomeInterface> {}
typealias Specified = Generic<Self>
class Self : SomeInterface
```

As for your original problem. I don`t think you can achieve this fully but the number of type parameters necessary could be reduced like this:

```
class ExampleFragment : SuperFragment<ExampleFragment>(), ExampleMVP.View {
    // final fragment logic
}

private typealias SuperFragment<T> = MVPFragment<
        T,
        ExampleMVP.View,
        ExampleMVP.Presenter,
        ExampleMVP.Args,
        ExampleMVP<ExampleMVP.View, ExampleMVP.Args>>
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. `Self`must not inherit from `Specified` as this creates a circular dependency. I don´t see that this is necessary in your example. If it is please provide a more detailed example. I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution which solves most of the problem.

Comment: Okay, that's seems like the way to go in this case